# LIferay get configured email address for notifications

Tags: email, liferay-7

I have configured the Liferay email, from Server Administration (Admin->Control Panel->Server Administration->Mail), both SMTP and POP. Anyway, I have not found a way to programmatically get the SMTP and POP e-mail addresses that I have configured.

Answer (score 1):

It appears I have to use

```
PrefsPropsUtil.getString(PropsKeys.MAIL_SESSION_MAIL_SMTP_USER);
PrefsPropsUtil.getString(PropsKeys.MAIL_SESSION_MAIL_POP3_USER);
```